# codeigniter routing to another project?

Tags: codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I've 2 CI projects, i would like to link the URI together

say

/project1/controller_abc/cdf to point -> /project2/controller/cdf
(cdf function does not exist in the controller_abc, would just like to map that to project2)

Is it possible to do routing to another project in routes.php of the codeigniter framework ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to something like that with an htaccess file

```
// check if the function/page is valid
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/project1/controller_abc/$1 !-f
// if it's not valid, go to the second project
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$  /project2/controller/$1  [L]
```